# Add Service Reference Error 405 ,The client and service bindings may be mismatched

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, wcf

I have created a WCF services, and I did not change anything in it, in both the configuration file and the code. I added it as a reference using "Add Service Reference", locally on the same PC and it worked correctly.
However when I deploy it to the server and try to add a service reference to it, and error is thrown:

```
   Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service https://www.tcs-ksa.net:1204/shm-dev/Service1.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8
```

**Config File Of the Service**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
      
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**Client Config File**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:54794/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to change the binding to WebHttpBinding like this:

```
binding="basicHttpBinding"
```

And add `content-type` as this when you make request:

```
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Where to make this, in the client config or in the service config? and under which section, can you please provide a more clear solution?

Comment: The above binding is configured on both the server and client side, and the Content-Type is added when you make the request.